# Get detail about super class by scala macros

Tags: scala, macros

how can I get type alias from super class by sub class macros?

for following code

```
trait AA {
    type T
}

@getsclass
trait BB extends AA {

}
```

I want to get detail about AA during macros in BB.

This [annotation macro that rewrites and impls a trait, generics not processed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34023763/annotation-macro-that-rewrites-and-impls-a-trait-generics-not-processed-correct)  do not work for me with not found typecheck exception.